# Выход из приложения по кнопке

Tags: android

Как сделать кнопку, по нажатию которой будут закрываться все активности?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такой метод:
`finish()` который завершит вашу активность, но приложение все-равно остается в открытых приложениях, и для того чтобы его убрать оттуда нужно завершать процесс. Так же есть функция [finishAffinity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity()) которая так же подойдет для решения вашей задачи.

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо.